# Files on my USB gets corrupted and content set to the letter ÿ

Tags: file-corruption

I have been having a problem on a USB. Whenever I save any type of file, it will get corrupted, and when opening any of these files with notepad, everything is set to the letter *"ÿ"*.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

I am using Windows 10 operating system, whenever I try to write to it, Windows does now show the writing process, but yet still copies a file to it, then it dissapears form the drives list and i have to unplug it and plug it back in. It says:

> "There is a problem with this drive. Scan the drive now and fix it."

Whenever it is plugged in, and is very hard to wipe as it takes multiple attempts, is there any way I can fix this? This happens with all file types I have tested.

Oddly, the names of all the files remain the same, its just the content that get set to the letter *"ÿ"*.

To answer some of the questions:
This is an old USB and, has not been tested on another computer, although I have not had any problems with the USB ports on my computer, and still do not now, and I am aware you can only open .txt files with notepad, but for the purposes of testing and the fact I cannot open the other files (due to them being corrupt),  I have opened them with notepad, all files, .txt and not all get set to the letter "ÿ".

Comment: `ÿ` is `FF` in  ANSI, binary `11111111`. The USB drive may be dying. Have you tested with another computer?

Comment: Is this an old or a new flash drive?

Comment: Please note, you can only open text files (`.txt`) with Notepad. Binary files result in "letter salad".

Comment: Unless you test with another computer and it turns out the USB drive works well there (unlikely IMO), the answer to the linked question applies: "your USB drive is toast, throw it away".